# The abbreviation of words

Tags: discussion, reference

Is there a comprehensive dictionary of abbreviations out there or, failing that, a document wherein one can find the accepted "rules" to abbreviate words in the English language?

Please, let me thank you in advance for your continued support.

Comment: Many [dictionaries](https://onelook.com/?w=abbr&ls=a) list standard abbreviations.

Comment: There are web sites such as [AcronymFinder](https://www.acronymfinder.com/) where you can look up the "popular" meanings for an acronym.

Comment: Voting to close?

Comment: Hi Jose.  I hope this helps.  I found this on Google by searching for abbreviation dictionary.  http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199698295.001.0001/acref-9780199698295

Comment: @Lumberjack: Thanks a lot for letting me know about it!

Answer (score 5):

There's certainly no *comprehensive* dictionary of abbreviations, as any individual, company, or even fandom can easily have its own abbreviations on top of any standard ones. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_abbreviations) is probably your best bet for a *somewhat* complete list, but this will still be missing a lot of more specific abbreviations. For example, as of right now, [DM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_acronyms:_D#DM) is missing the definition "direct message", which is common in Discord chat rooms.

English uses many sorts of [abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation) (which are generally considered to include acronyms, etc., especially in common speech), and there really is no set rule to how to abbreviate. As such, most [sources](https://www.grammarbank.com/abbreviation-rules.html) on "abbreviation rules" list how to *use* abbreviations rather than how to *make* them. Those that [do](https://www.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxford/media_wysiwyg/University%20of%20Oxford%20Style%20Guide.pdf) tend to say "these are the categories" with no rules on how or when to apply each category.

So let me lay out the most common forms of abbreviation, based on both [Oxford](https://www.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxford/media_wysiwyg/University%20of%20Oxford%20Style%20Guide.pdf) and personal experience:

- Removing everything except the first syllable. (Example: "Sat" for "Saturday" or "Eng" for "English")
- Removing vowels and duplicated consonants (Example: "sml" for "small" or "rng" for "range")
- Taking only the first letter(s) of the word(s) (Example: "M" for "Monday" or "UAE" for "United Arab Emirates")
- Combining the first syllables of multiple content words (Example: "satnav" for "satellite navigation system" or "SECNAV" for "Secretary of the Navy")
- Removing the middle of a word, leaving only a few letters from the beginning and end (usually one each) (Example: "st" for "saint" or also "street")

However, which type of abbreviation is called for is decided entirely by the individual word, and many words have multiple abbreviations. On various calenders, for example, "Thursday" may be abbreviated "Thurs", "[Thu](https://www.123calendars.com/images/2018/January/january-2018-calendar-1.jpg)", "[Th](https://omextemplates.content.office.net/support/templates/en-us/lt04068896.png)", "[T](http://calendarzone.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Calendar-1.png)", or even "[R](https://www.mvcc.edu/student-announcements/news-story/t-is-for-tuesday-r-is-for-thursday)" (to keep it straight from Tuesday). Not to mention, there are also words that use different sorts of abbreviations, too.

Overall, because abbreviations are not standardized, but rather created out of convenience, there really will never be a complete list of every abbreviation in English, nor comprehensive rules for how to make abbreviations.